# Font Size Changes in iOS unexpectedly

Tags: ios, fonts, display

All
I'm new to iOS and SwiftUI (2 months). I'm struggling to understand the following behavior and hope someone can point me as to how I can diagnose.

I have this code successfully generating this view in the preview provider

[image]

however when I run it on a device or in the simulator the fonts change (happens for system images also) to look more like this (scaled up).

[image]

The view below is rendered inside of a very generic tabview - I cant fathom it at all and could use some guidance.

Thanks

Craig

```
    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            HStack(alignment: .top){
                Text(player.firstName)
                    .bold()
                Text(player.lastName)
                    .bold()
            }
            .font(.title)
            HStack {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: player.playerPhoto) ?? UIImage())
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.purple, lineWidth: 4.0))
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("lifetime averages")
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        VStack {
                            Text("Batting")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .bold()
                            Text("\(battingAverage, specifier: "%.3f")")
                        }
                        .padding(.leading)
                        if isPitcher {
                            Spacer()
                            VStack {
                                Text("ERA")
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .bold()
                                Text("\(earnedRunAverage, specifier: "%.2f")")
                            }
                            .padding(.trailing)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("\(noTeams)")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("teams")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
                .padding(.leading, 10)
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("\(noSeasons)")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("seasons")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("\(noGames)")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("games")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }.padding(.trailing, 10)

            }
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Text("All Lifetime Stats >")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 200, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not specify a `.font(...)` for those two `Text` elements.

Is it possible you have set the ***default*** font somewhere else?

I can reproduce what you're getting by doing this (using `PlayerView` as a stand-alone view, not in a table).

If using `UIKit App Delegate`, in `willConnectTo session`:

```
    let contentView = PlayerView()
        .font(.largeTitle)
```

or, if using `SwiftUI App`:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            PlayerView()
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed - putting the .font(.body) in the tab view that was calling it solved it. I very much appreciate the instruction. I learned something.